# How to capture suspend event in Qt Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, resume

Working on Linux and using Qt to develop my application. I need to preserve the state of my application when it goes to suspend so while it come out to resume I can do the task accordingly. Please help me how to capture suspend/resume event in Linux using Qt.

Tried to find out the solution on Net but didn't found any solution. To capture the resume event we used system timestamp and it works but didn't know how to capture the suspend event.

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly save any state? The whole point of OS suspend/resume is that it automatically handles saving (and later restoring) the state of every running process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Qt way to detect when computer goes to sleep or hibernation. But there are some platform dependent ways to do it.

On linux you can put the following shell script in /etc/pm/sleep.d which executes a program with arguments. You can start a program and notify your main application in some way :

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
suspend)
    #suspending to RAM
    /Path/to/Program/executable Sleeping
    ;;
resume)
    #resume from suspend
    sleep 3
    /Path/to/Program/executable Woken
    ;;
esac
```